# Outlook - Search Routine Only Works In Debug Mode

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

I have a routine in C# to search for contacts in Outlook by filtering the Contact folder and it works when I debug it step by step, but if I let it run alone (without debug break) then it just do nothing, the results returned by Outlook are only empty arrays, no exception, nothing. This is the routine:

```
private List<Outlook.ContactItem> filterContactFolder(String searchStr, Outlook.Folder folder)
{
    List<Outlook.ContactItem> contacts = new List<Outlook.ContactItem>();

    string filter = "urn:schemas:contacts:fileas LIKE '%" + searchStr + "%'";
    Outlook.Search searchObject = null;
    String scope = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        scope = "'" + folder.FolderPath + "'";
        searchObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, false, Type.Missing);

        foreach (Outlook.ContactItem c in searchObject.Results)
        {
            contacts.Add(c);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (searchObject != null) searchObject.ReleaseComObject();
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

Anybody has an idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to get the results too early.

The key fact is that the search is performed in another thread. You need to handle the [AdvancedSearchComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864775(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when the AdvancedSearch method has completed.

You may find the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer, I finally ended up implementing [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863973.aspx) approach from Microsoft to handle the `AdvancedSearchComplete` event. It is simple and works very well.